# Absolute address of a file in MAUI

Tags: path, resources, maui, absolute, raw

I do not know the absolute address of a file in fill

Hello
I want to get the absolute address of a file added in the Raw folder in the MAUI project so that it works correctly when moving or installing the program on other systems. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: To read any file bundled with app, see [File System Helpers / Bundled files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=android#bundled-files).

Comment: the **absolute** address will vary per install.  A file bundled with the application should always have the same **relative** path from the app bundle

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The file added in the Raw folder in the MAUI project will be packaged into the apk file in the android. In addition, if you just want to read the file, you can use the file system helper and it can't be written.